# Error LNK2019 when building Tensorflow debug

Tags: c++, windows, tensorflow, linker

I try make a debug build of the CPU version of the C++ API of Tensorflow 2.0 in Windows. The command I use for building is:

```
bazel build -c dbg --copt=/w34716 tensorflow:tensorflow.dll
```

But when I build this I get this error:

```
depth_space_ops.lo.lib(depthtospace_op.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl tensorflow::functor::DepthToSpaceOpFunctor<struct Eigen::GpuDevice,struct Eigen::half,1>::operator()(struct Eigen::GpuDevice const &,class Eigen::TensorMap<class Eigen::Tensor<struct Eigen::half const ,4,1,__int64>,16,struct Eigen::MakePointer>,int,class Eigen::TensorMap<class Eigen::Tensor<struct Eigen::half,4,1,__int64>,16,struct Eigen::MakePointer>)" (??R?$DepthToSpaceOpFunctor@UGpuDevice@Eigen@@Uhalf@2@$00@functor@tensorflow@@QEAAXAEBUGpuDevice@Eigen@@V?$TensorMap@V?$Tensor@$$CBUhalf@Eigen@@$03$00_J@Eigen@@$0BA@UMakePointer@2@@4@HV?$TensorMap@V?$Tensor@Uhalf@Eigen@@$03$00_J@Eigen@@$0BA@UMakePointer@2@@4@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl tensorflow::DepthToSpaceOp<struct Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice,struct Eigen::half>::Compute(class tensorflow::OpKernelContext *)" (?Compute@?$DepthToSpaceOp@UThreadPoolDevice@Eigen@@Uhalf@2@@tensorflow@@UEAAXPEAVOpKernelContext@2@@Z)
```

The only thing I found regarding this issue was [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21758) GitHub issue, which wasn't solved.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using [tensorflow-windows-build-script](https://github.com/guikarist/tensorflow-windows-build-script)

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same necessity, I dug around in the code and actually found the source of the problem: It is contained in the following two `if` blocks: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/core/kernels/spacetodepth_op.cc#L129 and https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/core/kernels/depthtospace_op.cc#L115.

If you are building a non-GPU version of the library in debug, it is sort of clear why the error happens: the `if (std::is_same<Device, GPUDevice>::value)` for the `DepthToSpaceOp` class, for example, parametrized with CPUDevice, would evaluate to `if (false)` during compile time. With any optimizations enabled, the code in the if-clause (which explicitly triggers `DepthToSpaceOpFunctor` with a template parameter GPUDevice - exactly the missing symbols you are getting) would not be compiled at all, and therefore not need to be linked.

In the debug build, it is still likely compiled, even though it is clear that it will never be executed. Then the linker tries to find the `operator()` for the DepthToSpaceOpFunctor template-parametrized with GPUDevice, and fails to do so.

A quick-and-dirty way to fix this is to **comment out the entire if-clauses** (if you are building a CPU-only dll) **in both files** mentioned above.

A more elegant solution is to avoid these linker errors <strike>via template specialization</strike> by changing the explicit references to GPUDevice to Device, since those will be in the code that is executed only when Device *is* GPUDevice. I will soon add a pull request to a similar [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41118) I raised on github, hopefully, after a bit more testing.

**Update:** The pull request is submitted, you can find the code changes to fix this particular set of linker errors here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/42307/files#

For a GPU debug dll - I am not sure why these errors would still be there, but there are yet other linking errors in this case anyway ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You pointed out the right thing. However, I still had a similar issue even though your pull request had been merged. The symbols for the combination of `CPUDevice` and `FORMAT_NCHW` (= 1) were missing.
Adding the partial speciallization for `<CPUDevice, T, FORMAT_NCHW>` with empty operator() or enclosing the if-block with `#if GOOGLE_CUDA || TENSORFLOW_USE_ROCM` and `#endif` could solve it.

Comment: Hi @takao, I am glad it helped you somewhat. Indeed, after the pull request was already merged, I discovered that the final merged version was flawed (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/42307#issuecomment-673954495)... There has been some discussion here and there, but I never got around to merge the correct version. The original code change (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/42268/files) should work, but it duplicates a but of code, which made the reviewer a bit unhappy...

Comment: Since then my need to compile TF under Windows disappeared (we switched to a different inference engine for the C++ applications), so I did not pursue it further.